# Spyder anaconda cloudera

Tags: pyspark, anaconda, cloudera, spyder

I work with Cloudera VM 5.4.2

I have a .py that I want to execute instruction by instruction.

I installed in my Cloudera VM Anaconda. And I try to use spyder.

My .py has the instruction

```
from pyspark.mllib.clustering import KMeans, KMeansModel


ImportError: No module named 'pyspark'
```

How have I to configure spyder to work with pyspark

Answer (score 0):

Add `SPARK_HOME` and `PYSPARK_HOME` in `.bashrc`. And makes sure `py4j` module is installed or not